# Swift での画面遷移が意図した通り動かない

Tags: swift, uikit

swiftで画面遷移をするコードを書いているのですが、うまくいきません。

実装しようとしている機能：navigationbar の右に配置したボタンをタップしてpush遷移する。

結果：実行してもエラーは出ないがタップしても遷移されない。タップしたときにボタンの関数の中にあるデバッグ用のprint文は実行されているのでボタン自体はできてそう。

swift初学者のため拙いコードかもしれませんがよろしくお願いします。

```swift
//最初の画面のコード
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let navBar = UINavigationBar(frame : CGRect(x: 0, y: 40, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 100 ))
    let navItem : UINavigationItem = UINavigationItem(title: "タイトル")

    override func viewDidLoad() {

 super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        navItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "遷移", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action:#selector(self.rightHandAction))
        navBar.pushItem(navItem, animated: true)
        self.view.addSubview(navBar)

    //画面遷移する関数 
    @objc func rightHandAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        print("right bar button action")
        let vcC : UIViewController = viewControllerConfig()
        let naviVC : UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vcC)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(naviVC,animated: true)
    }
}
```

```swift
//遷移先の画面のコード
import UIKit

class viewControllerConfig: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "Config"
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
    }

}
```

Comment: 「swift初学者」と書いておられるのですが、`UINavigationBar`をコードでインスタンス化するなど、経験者でも滅多にやらない極めて特殊なコーディングをしておられるようです。とりあえずstoryboardはどのように使用しておられるか、ご質問に追記していただけますでしょうか?

Answer (score 0):

`self.navigationController?` がnilだからでしょうね。

`rightHandAction()` 内の

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(naviVC,animated: true)
```

がアンラップされたタイミングで終了してるのだと思います。

`UINavigationBar` を自力で追加したりしないで、以下の参考リンクを元に `NavigationController` を正しく設定すればよいと思います。

**参考リンク**
[Swiftでの画面遷移についてまとめ - Qiita](https://qiita.com/superman9387/items/c006ced215352f28a7b9#navigationcontroller%E3%81%A7%E7%94%BB%E9%9D%A2%E9%81%B7%E7%A7%BB)

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます！

Comment: navigationvontrollerについての理解が不足してました。